# How to disable pop-out option in pdf viewer with google doc iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, google-docs, google-document-viewer

I am using following code to display pdf using google with iframe.. It's working fine.
But I want to disable "pop-out" option (which on click opening my pdf in new tab with google docs) shown on right upper corner beside zoomin option on my webpage. Is it possible?

Currently I am using following code -

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/files/myfile.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0">
```

Comment: Did you find out a way to this??

Answer (score 10):

Can use `sandbox` to stop the `popup` working inside `iframe`

```
<iframe 
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
/>
```

`allow-scripts`: to run javascript inside iframe. 
`allow-same-origin`: to allow loading file from google viewer.
without `allow-popups`, nothing will happen when users click on  `pop-out` icon.
Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: have the same issue as the OP.  I am looking to remove the button, but can't find a way due to cross-origin issues; so I was really hoping this would work, but it does not.  The popout button still opens to a new window.

Comment: correction....this DOES work! I realized after my first comment that I had applied the sandbox to the iFrame #1, and I was testing on iFrame #2. Is there anyway to suppress `Blocked opening` messages in the console?

Comment: it does work, but in the browser console I am getting a warning: `An iframe which has both allow-scripts and allow-same-origin for its sandbox attribute can escape its sandboxing` - I don't understand why its working if the two combined have the same effect as having no `sandbox=` at all.  Are there sandbox options that would be more effective without the warning?

Answer (score 0):

Run this javascript (sample with jQuery) on your page (I assume the class is the same for all clients)

```
$('.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-Wrql6b').remove();
```

Comment: Are you sure this code will work for third party iFrame?

Comment: @RavinderKumar No it doesn't.

Comment: the class will not be the same and it will be random each time. Also it won't work for a third party iframe.

Comment: 6 years later, the `class="ndfHFb-c4YZDc-Wrql6b"` that controls the whole pop-out button is still the same class.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is useful to remove preview button. Add this code onload function of your iframe. It's applied after iframe is loaded.

```
var head = $("#iframe").contents().find("head");
var css = '<style type="text/css">' +
          '.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-Wrql6b{display:none}; ' +
          '</style>';
$(head).append(css);
```

Comment: It's worked for me. Maybe the class name is different in your case, you change the class name of a head and try again.

Comment: If this ever did work is probably no longer does.  In a Cordova app, modifying the `<head>` is prevented due to `cross-origin` issue.  Unless you know a way around this?